# Is there any way to change a json selected key value by a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have this json example, that i show it to the user in the GUI with textarea. is there any way with a button click for example to change only the `third key` value for example to `"fourth value"` without changing the whole json? maybe is there a way to dynamucally build the json when reading it from file to the textaera in a way that it will be easy to acceess any key and change it's value?

```
{
    "first_key": "firs_value",
    "second_key": "second_value",
    "third_key": "third_value",    
    "tests": 
    [
        { 
            "object_1_a": "a",
            "object_1_b": "b"
            },
            { 
            "object_2_a": "a",
            "object_2_b": "b"
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example how to access and change the value of `third_key`:

```js
const json = {
    "first_key": "firs_value",
    "second_key": "second_value",
    "third_key": "third_value",    
    "tests": 
    [
        { 
            "object_1_a": "a",
            "object_1_b": "b"
            },
            { 
            "object_2_a": "a",
            "object_2_b": "b"
            }
    ]
}

console.log('before', json)

json['third_key'] = 'changed';

console.log('after', json)
```

Comment: if i read a json file and put it in a text area, i can read the json from the textarea and have it arranged like this instead of a text? because when its displayed on a text area its a plain text (string)